# How to make org.eclipse.jface.viewer.TableViewer resizable?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

I have written this stuff but it won't provide me the resizable feature of table.

```
Composite resultTableComposite = getToolkit().createComposite( parent );
GridData gridData = new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 );
gridData.heightHint = 300;
gridData.widthHint = 250;
resultTableComposite.setLayoutData( gridData );
TableColumnLayout tableLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
resultTableComposite.setLayout( tableLayout );
resultTable = new TableViewer( resultTableComposite,
                SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION );
getToolkit().adapt( resultTable.getTable() );
resultTable.getTable().setLinesVisible( true );
resultTable.getTable().setHeaderVisible( true );
```

The following image shows only 3 rows after filling 3 rows scroll added, but if we want to see 4 elements without scrolling we cant see. we want we can able to expand on resize the table:

[image: This image shows only 3 rows after filling 3 rows scroll added, but if we want to see 4 elements without scrolling we cant see. we want we can able to expand on resize the table]

Comment: Does `SWT.V_SCROLL` work [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet001TableViewer.java) for you?

Comment: The `heightHint` is setting the size. You would need to adjust that. If you are adding more data after the form has been shown you would also have to redo the form layout.